# C: How to find the max of an array of struct with recursion?

Tags: algorithm

I just ended my first exams session, passed (thanks to you).
I have one more question for you: I have to find the max of an array of struct and then printf the element of the array that has the max value in it, using a recursive algorithm. I've been smashing my head on the keyboard for about 1 week just to solve this, but I cannot seem to be able to do it. Can you help me?

Here's the code:
PLEASE, DON'T CARE ABOUT THOSE STRCPY, ty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    char autori[100];
    char titolo[100];
    int anno;
    int codice;
    float prezzo;
    char stato[50];
} libro;

int massimo(int m, int n );
libro ricorsivo(libro a[], int len);

void main()
{
    libro max;
    int len=30;
    libro elenco[100];

    strcpy(elenco[0].autori,"Angelo Ciaramella e Giulio Giunta");
    strcpy(elenco[0].titolo,"Manuale di Programmazione in C");
    elenco[0].anno=2009;
    elenco[0].codice=0;
    elenco[0].prezzo=0.0;
    strcpy(elenco[0].stato,"Disponibile");
    max=ricorsivo(elenco, len);
    printf ("il massimo vale %d", max);
}

libro ricorsivo(libro a[], int len)
{
    if (len==1)
        return a[0];
    else
        return massimo(a.prezzo[len-1],ricorsivo(a,len-1));
}

int massimo(int m, int n)
{
    if (n>m)
        return n;
    else if (m>n)
        return m;
}
```

The algorithm is incomplete, I know, but the most problematic parts are those functions. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: This is a wall of code. Please, provide ONLY the part of it that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints that should help you fix the code:

Firstly, your `massimo` (`max`) function is defined incorrectly. In the case where `m == n` this function returns nothing, this is not allowed. What you want is if `n > m` you return `n` otherwise simply return `m`, i.e.

```
int max(int m, int n) { return n > m ? n : m; }
```

Next, in your recursive function you have a few type errors in this line:

```
return massimo(a.prezzo[len-1], recorsivo(a, len-1))
```

- `a` is not of type `libro`, it is of type `libro[]` so it is not going to have a `prezzo` field.
- If `a` *were* of type `libro`, and you accessed its `prezzo` field, then that has type `float`, and so it would be incorrect to perform an array index on it.
- If `a.prezzo[len-1]` *did* produce the `prezzo` value of the `len-1`th element of the array, then that would have type `float`, but your `massimo` function accepts only `int`s.
- `ricorsivo(a, len-1)` returns a `libro` and it is being passed into `massimo` which takes an `int`.

To fix these issues try the following:

- Remove your `massimo` function, you don't need it.
- In the recursive case of your recursive function

  - Call it recursively to get the max from the rest of the array.
  - Compare the `prezzo` value from the max of the rest of the array, with the `prezzo` value from the element at `len-1`.
  - Return the `libro` with the larger `prezzo`.

You should be able to translate the above into some pretty straightforward C code.